# moving 4g AIX server to 6520 brocade switch, i/o errors on host

Tags: storage-area-network

Recently tried to move several HP Unix (AIX) servers from an old 5300 brocade switch fabric to new 6520 brocade fabric. The old zones were inactivated and old storage port id's were kept intact for failover should problems occur, the new storage ports were activated but the servers are encountering large volume of i/o errors? Also the old switches were running 6.4 FOS and new switches are running 7.4.2a if that means anything. Thank You in advance